# Form reference causing Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll

Whenever I create the class:

```
class Trader : Form1
{
    public void changeText(string text) {
        changeLabel(text) //A method inside my Form1.Designer.cs
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm doing this wrong, I want to access and modify design elements
within the Windows Form I am using (Form1). Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, give (a lot) more details.

Comment: Added the method I'm using, which is within the Form1.Designer.cs @Amit

Comment: Does `changeLabel(text)` call `changeText(text)` by any chance?

Comment: You are calling changeLabel() method all over again. This causes the exception..

Comment: It doesn't. But even when I comment out that code I get this exception.

Comment: Doesn't the exception include a stacktrace that will show you what methods are being called repeatedly?

Comment: Is the method maybe called by a event handler that reacts on a text changed event?

Comment: @OskarBerggren It doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Console I don't think so. Would calling : Form 1 in a second class mess it up at all?

Comment: When and where _exactly_ are you getting that exception?

Answer (score -1):

I was calling the class Trader within the class Form1.